# "Fatal Error attempting to save" in Maya 2009

Tags: windows, maya

I am facing a problem when I start Maya 2009. I am getting

> Fatal Error attempting to save in `c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\locals\xxxxx.2010..`

I tried reinstalling Maya many times, but it didn't help.

Comment: Now why would you think this is programming related?

Comment: ask on http://www.vfxoverflow.com/, those guys dream about maya.

Comment: See [this thread](http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/108298-Maya-quot-Fatal-Error-Attempting-to-save-quot-when-starting). Not quite the same thing, but seems related.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting "maya" folder in your users "document and settings", this might be a corrupted userSetup.mel .
Change your video drivers ?